# How to do facet search with mpdreamz Nest

Tags: elasticsearch

does anybody know how to do facet search with Nest?
My index is https://gist.github.com/3606852
would like to search for some keyword in 'NumberEvent' and dispaly the result if the keyword exist.Please help me !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using the assumption that the `MyPoco` class exists and maps to your elasticsearch document. If it doesn't you can use `dynamic` but you'l have to swap the lambda based field selectors with strings.

```
var result = client.Search<MyPoco>(s=>s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Filter(ff=>ff.
        .Term(f=>f.Categories.Types.Events.First().NumberEvent.event, "keyword")
    )
    .FacetTerm(q=>q.OnField(f=>f.Categories.Types.Facets.First().Person.First().entity))
);
```

`result.Documents` now holds your documents

`result.Facet<TermFacet>(f => f.Categories.Types.Facets.First().Person.First().entity);` now holds your facets

Your document seems a bit strange though in the sense that it already has Facets with counts in them.

Comment: I am new to Elasticsearch and Nest and quite unaware that how to map elasticsearch document to Nest.. can you give some helps on mapping ??

Comment: Thanks @Martijn for the great help and I am sorry to disturb you again with this simple question :

Comment: var result= client.Search(s => s
.From(0)
.Size(10).Filter(ff => ff.
Term("Categories.Types.Events.NumberEvent.event", "notable")
)
.FacetTerm(q => q.OnField("Categories.Types.Events.NumberEvent.event"))
); This workh for me.The problem I faced was because of implicit lowercasing with default Analyser ..